# Burgermenu: slideToggle if click on icon and slideUp if click somewhere else (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to show the items from a burger menu if the user clicks on its icon and hide the item again if the user clicks somewhere else. My first (and current) idea is like this:

```
$('.brgIcon').on('click',function(){
   $('.brgItem').slideToggle();
   $('html').on('click',function(){
        $('.brgItem').slideUp();
        $('html').off('click');       
    })
})
```

But it wont work nice. The items slide down and directly up again.
Whats wrong?

Thx :-)

Update: fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/mikexmagic/ap0mtuzs/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.stopPropagation() to prevent the call of html click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.brgIcon').on('click',function(e){
   $('.brgItem').slideToggle();
   e.stopPropagation();
 });

  $('html').on('click', function(){
     $('.brgItem').slideUp();
  })
})
```

To understand this behaviour please see capturing and bubbling of events in javascript. 
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

because `$('.brgIcon')` is a part of `$('html').on('click',function(){...` when you click on hamMenu it'll both `slideDown` and `slideUp` at the same time. so you won't catch any difference on your screen(most probably).
what you have to do is put your menu container in another division with `width` and `height` of 100%, and `position` of fixed. and 'onClick' slide the whole container down.
In this case you'd be able to select `$('container:not(.menu)').click` which will `slideUp` the menu.
I hope you can figure it out:)